# CSS div under divs

Tags: css, html, css-float, z-index

I'm not skilled with CSS, this is one of my first projects. I was trying to make a CSS style for a slider I have, I want something like this:

[image: Image Slider]

I've made succesfully the inner divs and the button divs, but what troubles me is the index order for the next/previous buttons on the slider.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
<div><a href="#" id="rhandle">&gt;</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="lhandle">&lt;</a></div>
<div id="loadingBar"></div>
<div class="slide">
    <div id="leftSlide">
        <h1>WhiteFox Template</h1>
        <p>Buy this theme today with all features, All fonts included in this theme are for personal use only. <br />Detailed documentation included.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div id="rightSlide">
        <img src="images/slides/slide-1.gif" width="259" height="184" alt="slide-1 Image" />
    </div>
    <div style="height:0;line-height:0;display:block;clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS for the slider:

```
.slider {
height: 329px;
width: 794px;
background: #313131;
margin: 50px auto 80px;
color: #FFF;
}

.slider a#lhandle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4bacfd;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.slider a#rhandle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4bacfd;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.slider a#lhandle:hover,
.slider a#rhandle:hover {
    color: #4bacfd;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #4bacfd;
    width: 48px;
    height: 21px;
}

.slider #loadingBar {
    background: #a0a0a0;
    height: 6px;
}

.slider .slide {
    height: 328px;
    width: 793px;
    position: relative;
}



.slider .slide h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.slider .slide div#leftSlide {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 328px;
}


.slider .slide div#rightSlide {
    float: right;
    height: 328px;
    width: 280px;
}

.slider .slide img {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
}

.slider .slide p {
    display: block;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

This way, the next/previous buttons are below the actual content, when you hover over them, they do not change to ":hover" style. I've tryied adding a "z-index: 5" property, but that did not work, how can I achieve this (If there is an easier way, let me know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` will work, you just have to set a `position` other than `static` (which is the default value).

Add this to your handles on either side:

```
z-index:10;
position:relative;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QYnVc/

Side note: You can trim down a lot of your redundant CSS by either using common class names for similar elements, or by using multiple selectors for a group of CSS properties.  For example:

```
#rhandle,
#lhandle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4bacfd;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    z-index:10;
    position:relative;
}

#rhandle {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), the *z-index* property only works, when the affected items' *position* property is set to either *absolute*, *relative* or *fixed*.

Using those properties, you might have to reposition the items using *left*/*right* and *top*/*bottom* properties.

Comment: I've passed through W3schools and haven't noticed the big **NOTE**. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine with a `z-index` however z-index is only effective on positioned elements, so you need to also add something like `position:relative` to the handles.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HbWc3/)**

CSS:

```
.slider a#lhandle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4bacfd;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

.slider a#rhandle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4bacfd;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

On a side note you may want to reconsider how you've laid our your slides as there seems to be an excess of elements and CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using dreamweaver right now, I made this in a rush and didn't fix the code yet. Thanks for the tips! :)